# Customizing login message

Tags: errors

I’m trying to change this error “The username [username here] is not registered on this site. If you are unsure of your username, try your email address instead.” I’ve tried various methods and can’t figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried with the [`gettext` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/)? If so, what's the code you used?

Comment: I tried the code from this thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/396851/customizing-login-error-messages

Comment: What should the code look like? I’d like to change it to say “The email [username here] is not registered on this site.”

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variation of this code to change invalid login messages (adjust the message to your needs; but see note below):

```
add_filter('login_errors', function ($error) {
    global $errors;
    $err_codes = $errors->get_error_codes();

    // Invalid username.
    if (in_array('invalid_username', $err_codes)) {
        $error = '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Sorry, that is incorrect.';
    }

    // Incorrect password.
    if (in_array('incorrect_password', $err_codes)) {
        $error = '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Sorry, that is incorrect.';
    }

    return $error;
});
```

In regards to the message, I have specified a more 'secure' message - one that will describe the problem, but won't give hints to a hacker trying to enumerate user IDs.

You should also block excessive login attempts.

Comment: Code doesn’t work unfortunately.

Comment: That exact code works in an active plugin I made to change the error messages on an unsuccessful login - I double-checked the code is correct. Please provide information on how it fails, and any error log messages. Here's the docs for that filter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_errors/ . And there are many search results with tutorials about how to use that filter, including this answer her: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/396857/29416